# Python how get /8 subnet for an IP addres

Tags: python, sdn, inetaddress, ryu

How can I get the /8 subnet containing a given ip address.
e.g., subnet 10.0.0.0/8 for ip 10.1.1.1

I tried it so for wit netaddr lib, but it doesn't do what it should

```
network = netaddr.IPNetwork(ip)
network.prefixlen=8
ip_subnet=network.cidr
```

ip is the given ip adress

Comment: Which version of Python are you using? Python 3.3+ has `ipaddress` in the stdlib which I believe does this...

Answer (score 1):

using ipaddr , first install the module

```
pip install ipaddr
```

then import IPv4Network from it

```
from ipaddr import IPv4Network

masknet = IPv4Network('192.168.1.1') # Ip Address
print masknet.netmask
# OR
masknet = IPv4Network('192.168.1.1/8')
print masknet.netmask
```

Result:

```
>>> print masknet.netmask
255.255.255.255
>>> print masknet.netmask
255.0.0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ip.network after creating IPNetwork()

```
ip = IPNetwork('10.1.1.1/8')
ip.network
Out[48]: IPAddress('10.0.0.0')
ip = IPNetwork('10.1.1.1/16')
ip.network
Out[50]: IPAddress('10.1.0.0')
ip = IPNetwork('10.1.1.1/24')
ip.network
Out[52]: IPAddress('10.1.1.0')
```